# Error while storing Users in firebase database

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, angularfire2

i got an error like this:

> core.js:6014 ERROR TypeError: Class constructor Observable cannot be invoked without 'new'
>
> ```
> at new FirebaseObjectObservable (firebase_object_observable.js:16)    
> at FirebaseObjectFactory (firebase_object_factory.js:7)    
> at AngularFireDatabase.push../node_modules/angularfire2/database/database.js.AngularFireDatabase.object (database.js:18)    
> at UserService.save (user.service.ts:12)
> at SafeSubscriber.next (app.component.ts:17)
> at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:185)    
> at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:124)
> at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:72)
> at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49    
> at Notification.observe (Notification.js:20)
> ```

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {        
    constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }
    save(user: firebase.User){
        this.db.object('/users/' + user.uid).update({
            name:user.displayName,
            email:user.email
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you initialize firebase in your app.module.ts via your config object?

Comment: yes @EnesYalçın  i did initialize it : AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase)

Comment: changed "target": "es2015", in the tsconfig file to "es5" . It worked

Answer (score 1):

For all those who get stuck on this in future, try changing  "target": "es2015", in the tsconfig file to "es5" . It worked for me.